# Foundation 5 and page printing

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation.
I'm trying to print a page exactly as it looks in large screen but everything get stacked (and floated wrong).

I succeded in having the grid in the printing page by substituting every "screen" occurrences with "print, screen" in the foundation.min.css.

The problem is that the grid taken now is the small one.

I read this post on the foundation support but honestly I don't know exactly what I'm supposed to do. Do I need to recompile foundation with sass?

http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/412-printing-paper-copies-of-site-built-on-foundation

Whats should I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the CSS for that:

```
@media print {
  .large-1 {
    width: 8.33333%;
  }

  .large-2 {
    width: 16.66667%;
  }

  .large-3 {
    width: 25%;
  }

  .large-4 {
    width: 33.33333%;
  }

  .large-5 {
    width: 41.66667%;
  }

  .large-6 {
    width: 50%;
  }

  .large-7 {
    width: 58.33333%;
  }

  .large-8 {
    width: 66.66667%;
  }

  .large-9 {
    width: 75%;
  }

  .large-10 {
    width: 83.33333%;
  }

  .large-11 {
    width: 91.66667%;
  }

  .large-12 {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Source: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/2820-printing-foundation-5

Comment: Works like charm! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

These three sass loops have made my life easier when styling pages for print and have worked like a charm.

The variable $total-columns comes from foundation's core settings.

```css
  @for $i from 1 through $total-columns {
    .large-#{$i} {
      width: 100% * ($i/$total-columns);
    }
  }

  @for $i from 1 through $total-columns {
    .medium-#{$i} {
      width: 100% * ($i/$total-columns);
    }
  }

  @for $i from 1 through $total-columns {
    .small-#{$i} {
      width: 100% * ($i/$total-columns);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to recompile foundation with sass?

Well, yes. You need to create a custom sass file and put the print rules inside that. Then recompile the file with Sass compiler.

Inside the `scss/` folder you have these two `normalize.scss` and `foundation.scss` files. Create a new file named `app.scss` and import the normalize and foundation as follows:

```
// Import the normalize.scss
@import "normalize";

// Import the foundation.scss
@import "foundation";

// Your own SCSS here...
```

And then put the below code snippet at the end of `app.scss` file **[as suggested](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/2111-print-as-shown-for-medium-up)** by [*Rafi Benkual*](http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/users/10):

> For example you could force the large grid to be print friendly by
>   adding in the following code to your project:

```
// This would make the large grid function like a print grid
@media print {
  @for $i from 1 through $total-columns {
    .large-#{$i} {
      width: gridCalc($i, $total-columns);
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** This may or may not work. I didn't try this myself. However it's deemed helpful at  *Foundation Forum*.

The `$total-columns` variable is defined in [`scss/foundation/components/_grid.scss`](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/5.1-wip/scss/foundation/components/_grid.scss#L11) file, which you can override that (as the other settings) by editing [`scss/foundation/_settings.scss`](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/5.1-wip/scss/foundation/_settings.scss#L36). Hence you need to import `@import "foundation/settings";` before the foundation file.

Finally, [compile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14232340/compile-sass-on-windows) the `app.scss` file by: `sass --watch app.scss:app.css`

Comment: see Sas Sam's answer below `gridCalc()` is depreciate in favor of `grid-calc()`

Answer (score 1):

Follow @Hashem Qolami's answer, but need a small change in for loop because for some reason it doesn't calculate the percentage value for columns and also the `gridCalc()` already [deprecated (line #22)](https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/v5.2.3/scss/foundation/components/_grid.scss) in Foundation 5. So you should use the `grid-calc()` instead or much better if you calculate the percentages directly with `percentage()`:

```
@media print {
  @for $i from 1 through $total-columns {
    .large-#{$i} {
      width: percentage($i / $total-columns);
    }
  }
}
```

It will do the basic things but need more hacks if you created a custom HTML structure with some tricks.

Set the width for the whole html to large size:

```
@media print {
  html {
    width: rem-calc(1280px);
  }

  @for $i from 1 through $total-columns {
    .large-#{$i} {
      width: percentage($i / $total-columns);
    }
  }
}
```

And finally in the `_settings.scss` (around line #82) set the `$screen` value from `"only screen"` to `"only print, screen"`:

```
$screen: "only print, screen";
```

Comment: Hi - I have been using this for large screen and has been working good. Now I converted this angular website to android app but print layout is not same as  the screen display, I repeated the for loop with .small and .medium - but no change, any idea? Thanks