# Set Up Foundation For Printing

Tags: html, css, printing, zurb-foundation

I am attempting to set up our newest foundation build out for print and I'm having some major issues getting their grid to play nice with it.  Is there any 'reset' style stylesheet out there?  Anybody had this issue before and have some advice?  I've tried everything from displaying rows as table-rows and columns as table cells, tried setting auto widths with floats, the closest I could get was defining a set width for each number on the grid and it still didn't come out correctly (maybe a little closer).  Thanks for any advice or help you all can provide!

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21657445/foundation-5-and-page-printing/21658718#21658718

Comment: Tried adding the snippet to my code where you said and it gave me an error that $total-columns was undefined so I defined it as 12 and it didn't do anything to the print screen.  Is this not the way it was meant to work?

Comment: First of all, please check the output CSS file to ensure that it's compiled correctly. Second, note that I've used `large-*` classes for the columns in the snippet code. If you've used a different class (e.g. `small-` or `medium-`), replace that in the snippet.

Comment: I couldn't get it to work but I really appreciate you taking the time to try to help me.  I ended up just throwing id's on the major divs I needed to target since this won't be massive.  Hopefully this helps somebody in the future.